# Can jqxTextArea's Font Be Modified?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use jqxTextArea as a read-only text summary that holds statistics such as male, female, and GPA that is updated via AJAX.  The font is bit small (11px) and I want to bump it to 18px.  I tried to add "font-size: 18px" to the text area div block's style, but it appears that jquery's .css is overridding the font-size.

I can use VS's debugger to manually insert the font-size in textarea, but I don't know where to actually put font-size where it won't get clobbered.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the answer.

Short Answer:

```
$('#jqxTextArea textarea').css('font-size','18px')
```

Longer Answer: I had to access the piece of jqxTextArea that was getting overridden by jqx-widget-content css because writing in the style of the jqxText Area's DIV block was not working ('textarea' happened to be two children deep in the jqxTextArea DIV block).  Using 'textarea' as part of the jquery selector with the .css() function call did the trick.